# Copying, Renaming and Populating a Cell in Copied Sheet in 1 Step

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Button_8()
worksheets("Template_MM").Select
worksheets("Template_MM").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 
ActiveSheet.Name = Sheets("Home").Cells(6, 2)
Dim Closing_Date As String
worksheets("Home").Select
Closing_Date = Range("B5")
'Trying to copy cell B5 in the Home tab to C3 in the duplicate of Template_MM that i just created
End Sub
```

I am trying to write VBA code to do the following with the click of a button (Button_8):

1. Copy a hidden sheet I have in the workbook
2. Renaming it based on what I have typed in cell B6 of the Home tab
3. Inserting into C3 of the new copied sheet the closing date I have populated in cell B5 of the Home tab

I have accomplished Steps #1 and #2 with the above code but am really struggling on how to build off the code and get step #3 to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub Button_8()
worksheets("Template_MM").Select
worksheets("Template_MM").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 
ActiveSheet.Name = Sheets("Home").Cells(6, 2)

Range("C3") = Sheets("Home").Range("B5")

End Sub
```